# How to write out tkinter focus selection to Excel file at a particular location

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, excel, tkinter

So I have a selection returned by following function, this gets the entries for the selected row and columns `fenceLabel` & `Comment` and allows me to update in treeview successfully but I'm failing to write back to Excel file successfully.

```
def update_record():
    # Grab record number
    selected = my_tree.focus()

    # Update Record
    my_tree.set(selected, "fenceLabel", fl_spinbox.get())
    my_tree.set(selected, "Comment",cnt_entry.get())
```

My issue is to write this out to an excel file being used as source of treeview upon which I want write and read from with the tkinter treeview.

I have tried adding this to function above

```
# Update Excel File

    excel_file = "output.xlsx"
    file_path = Path.cwd() / excel_file

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

    # Get button entry values
    faller_df.loc[selected, "fenceLabel"] = fl_spinbox.get()
    faller_df.loc[selected , "Comment"] = cnt_entry.get()

    faller_df.to_excel("fallers_output.xlsx")
```

But all it those is add values to next empty row, appending to rows/records but to the right columns at least. I have created a unique key `fallerId` so maybe this can help me to use with `focus` selection?